# A class gets unique property backing even if property backed by static variable

Tags: objective-c

Seems like the property just doesn't get backed by the static variable, and the compiler gives it a unique one, anyway.

header file:

```
@interface MyBase : NSObject
@property int error;
@end

@interface MySubclass : MyBase
@end
```

Implementation file:

```
static int staticError = 0;

@implementation MyBase
@synthesize error = staticError;            // back it with a static variable
@end

@implementation MySubclass
@end
```

Example:

```
MyBase* base = [[MyBase alloc] init];
base.error = 1;

MyBase* anotherBase = [[MyBase alloc] init];
NSAssert( base.error == anotherBase.error , @"This causes assertion" );

MySubclass* subClass = [[MySubclass alloc] init];
subClass.error = 2; // This *should* set our static variable from 1 to 2.

// Prove they refer to the same static variable (but fail)
NSAssert( base.error == subClass.error , @"This causes assertion" );
```

Tested on Xcode 6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: `@property` declares *and only* declares one (for `readonly` set) or two *instance* *methods*. In really no case it defines an instance variable or any other kind of variable.

There is no reason to have *instance* methods for a global variable. Such a global variable is literally no property. Property of what?

If you want to have such a global storage, you can add *class* methods to access it or simply functions. (The only benefit you get from using class methods is the ability to overwrite it in a subclass, what is akin of meaningless.)

```
static int staticError = 0; // int? really int? staticError? Really staticError?

+ (int)error { return staticError; }
+ (void)setError:(int)error { staticError = error; }
```

Or

```
int baseError { return staticError; }
void setBaseError(int error) { staticError = error; }
```

Comment: By default, a property does in fact have an instance variable automatically generated in addition to the setter and getter instance methods. So your opening paragraph is incorrect.

Comment: No, ivar definition is *solely* provided by the synthesizing. By default and under some circumstances a property has a hidden synthesize, so on a first view one might get into confusion with that. But this does not change the fact, that property is a method declaration and nothing else than a method declaration.

Comment: Yes, the ivar comes from the synthesizing which comes from the property. Therefore, by default (through the default auto synthesis), a property declaration results in an ivar. But all of this aside, what was the point of your first paragraph? It has nothing to do with the question. The OP had an explicit call to `@synthesize` and that synthesis does not work like the OP thought. Hence my answer which explained the problem. Your answer doesn't explain the problem in the question but offers an alternative solution instead.

Comment: No, solely the synthesizing causes the definition of the ivar. This depends on many conditions, one of this condition is `@property`. Another one is the existence of an interface containing the property declaration, an implementation where the synthesizing can take place, an `@synthesize` for having an explicit synthesizing or no getter and – for rw-properties – no setter for having an implicit synthesizing, … [2b continued]

Comment: There are a bunch of preconditions. This does not change the fact, that solely the synthesizing creates the ivar. If there is an synthesizing, then you get a creation (if needed). If there is no synthesizing, then there is no creation. Period. Nothing else.  Quite simple. Bonus question: Why can a protocol contain an `@property` while it cannot have ivars?

Comment: My answer shows the right way to do what he wants to do. I'm pretty sure (and hope) that there are dozens of answers you gave to a questioner that he does something at the very beginning. – Furthermore I did not start a pedantic discussion. The hint that the `@property` does not create the ivar was necessary, because the questioner had exactly the wrong assumption you had. Read the title of the Q. He talks about properties and backing (=ivar).

Comment: Every statement in an answer has to be wrong to get a downvote? I do not think so: Even an answer contains correct parts, it can be downvoted. My answer explains, why it does not work: Because `@property` is the wrong concept for providing access to static vars.

Comment: "By default, a property does in fact have an instance variable automatically generated in addition to the setter and getter instance methods. So your opening paragraph is incorrect." A property does not generate an instance var and the first paragraph is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The line `@synthsize error = staticError;` does not do what you think it does.

It will use (and create if needed) an *instance* variable named `staticError`. This will be completely different from the static variable named `staticError`.

If you really (and why?) want to use a static variable as the backing store for the property, then remove the `@synthesize` line and add your own explicit setter and getter methods for the property. Their implementation should use the static variable.

Comment: I downvoted your answer, because you gave the advice to implement an (instance) accessor pair for a static var that in consequence is being shared between all instances. This is a violation of everything OOP teaches about data encapsulation. In his code the usage of @property is wrong, not the synthesization. It is no property of an instance.

Comment: rmaddy is more than aware of that.  He wasn't making a value judgement; he was just explaining how to accomplish what the questioner sought to do.

Comment: The questioner had the Q, why he gets an ivar, when he declares a property and connect the synthesizing to a static var: "A class gets unique property backing even if property backed by static variable" There are two solutions for it: 1. (rmaddy) Continue using a property and surpress ivar creation. 2. Do not use properties for this. The first answer violates basic OOP principles as explained. One should not give that. I do not know, whether this is a "value judgement". If it is, one should make it. – I do not vote for persons. I vote for answers. I'm pretty sure that this in intended by SO.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Lets be clear. I do not think that using a static variable for an instance variable is appropriate. My answer simply pointed out that if the OP really did want to do that, there is a solution. Read the last paragraph of my answer. You can see that I question why the OP would want this.